# Polar to cartesian 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the 2nd order ODE: $\dfrac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} + u = \dfrac{k}{h}(2+\sin2\theta)^{-3/2}$

I'm asked to solve this and convert to cartesian to obtain the solution:

$1 - Ax - By = \dfrac{k\sqrt{2}}{3h^2}(x^2+xy+y^2)^{1/2}$, and given a hint to use a particular integral proportional to $\sqrt{2+\sin2\theta}$

So, for the CF I get $u = A_1 \cos \theta + A_2 \sin \theta$, for the PI I follow the hint and let $u = B \sqrt{2+\sin 2\theta}$

Receive $u' = B\cos 2\theta(2+\sin2\theta)^{-1/2}$ and $u'' = (-2Bsin2\theta)(2+sin2\theta)^{-1/2} -B\cos^2 2\theta(2+\sin2\theta)^{-3/2}$, so I sub this back into the original question and multiply by $(2+\sin 2 \theta)^{3/2}$ and receive this:

$B(2+\sin2\theta)^2 - 2B\sin2\theta(2+\sin 2\theta) - Bcos^2 2\theta = k/h^2$, and comparing coefficient terms I get $B =  k/4h^2$, however I do not get the correct answer by going back to cartesian with this value of B, could someone please show me where I have gone wrong? If I change the $\cos^22\theta$ to $1 - \sin^22\theta$ and compare coefficients I get the correct answer - could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Taking
$$
B(2+\sin2\theta)^2 - 2B\sin2\theta(2+\sin 2\theta) - Bcos^2 2\theta = \frac{k}{h^2}
$$
and expanding terms we get 
$$
B\left(4 + \sin^{2}2\theta + 4\sin2\theta\right) - 4B\sin2\theta - 2B\sin^{2}2\theta - B\cos^{2}2\theta =\\
4B + B\sin^{2}2\theta - 2B\sin^{2}2\theta  - B\cos^{2}2\theta = \frac{k}{h^{2}}
$$
Now you can reduce to yield
$$
4B - B\left(\sin^{2}2\theta  + \cos^{2}2\theta \right) = \frac{k}{h^{2}} = 3B
$$
I believe that you made a simple "book-keeping" error.
$$
B = \frac{k}{3h^{2}}
$$